# How would one use T4 to transform classes from one project into another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

Assume I have a project (say ProjectA) with a number of C# classes and that those classes do not reference any types outside of the project and that of the System.dll assembly. The classes in ProjectA may have methods, properties, fields and custom properties. Classes may also exist within different namespaces.

How would one go about using T4 to transform all those classes, including methods, properties, fields and custom attributes, from ProjectA, to a related set in another project (say ProjectB).

Comment: In such cases, I would usually add links to the code files, rather than clone them. If you’re convinced you want a copy, you could use `File.Copy` operations within your T4.

Comment: What makes you think T4 is the right tool for the job?

Comment: Do you want to keep namespace from *ProjectA* or change them to other (*ProjectB*) namespace?

Comment: Why not re-use your code - easier to maintain surely? Factor out the stuff you want to re-use into it's own code library, and reference it wherever needed. If you opt to create copies, and discover a bug 6 months from now, think of the pain it'll cause trying to update every copy...

Comment: Werner, can you share a little more of what you want the difference between the classes in project A and project B to be, so we can understand why just linking wouldn't work?

Comment: With T4 I can further transform the classes in ProjectB to satisfy a requirement such as using them with as entities in a data access layer or resources in a REST based service. In addition, this will also explain whether I can use T4 to generate Objective-C or Java classes from my C# classes.

Comment: @Matej Yes, the namespace should probably change.

Comment: Best option would be add files as a link, and setup conditional compilation symbols and declare namespace based on conditions

Comment: More directed to others comments than Werners but source code sharing as opposed to binary sharing has strengths and weaknesses. Patching can be more difficult but deployment can be significantly simplified. Adding links to files from other projects are difficult to maintain, personally when I have liked source code sharing I have used T4 to read source code from ProjectA into ProjectB (simulating the 40 year old invention of #include). It has worked great.

Comment: @RichardW1001 you have a point, but achieving reuse in some cases complicates a system. Consider the case where you have classes representing a data access layer which mimics your database closely.  Surely your database doesn't represent your view model (MVC) or service model (in a REST API). Isn't it more maintainable to separate concerns and have similar object models between services, views and use AutoMapper to map between them? I would hate it if a change to my database suddenly invalidates my REST API or effects the usability of my UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Werner, you can certainly do this.  A good technique is to use VS's Code Model.
There's some pointers to examples here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/garethj/archive/2009/09/25/dte-and-t4-better-together.aspx

You'd use code model to read the classes in as metadata without compiling and then generate using that metadata as input.  You might want to then look at Oleg Sych's T4 Toolbox ( http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com ) to project the ouput into the secondary project.

Comment: Although not finalized yet I would consider Roslyn: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27746

Comment: @GarethJ, thank you for the suggestion. I have searched for EnvDTE and T4 and found a couple of examples. Clearly my work is cut out for me.

Comment: @FuleSnabel I started playing with Roslyn and it seems like a good fit for this type of work and its far less work.